# Conservation of the $L^1$ norm in the Heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I consider the homogeneous Heat equation in $\textbf{R}^d \times (0,T]$ for a fixed $T>0$ :
\begin{cases} \partial_t f - \Delta f = 0 & \text{in } \textbf{R}^d \times (0,T] \\ f=f_0 & \text{on } \textbf{R}^d \times \{t=0\} \end{cases}
I want to show the conservation of the $L^1$ norm assuming that $f_0 \geq 0$ (and thus $f \geq 0$ by the maximum principle). I know that formally
$$0\stackrel{(1)}{=}\int_{\textbf{R}^d}{\Delta f}=\int_{\textbf{R}^d}{\partial_t f}\stackrel{(2)}{=}\partial_t \left(\int_{\textbf{R}^d}{f}\right)=\partial_t( \| f \|_{L^1})$$
but I got difficulties to justify $(1)$ and $(2)$ without making strong assumptions on $f$. I should also precise that I do not want to use the explicit solution given by the Fourier transform's method.

Can anyone help me ? Many thanks !

Comment: Why not use the actual solution for $f$ in terms of the convolution of $f_0$ with the heat kernel?

Comment: For some reasons : I am not sure that there is uniqueness of the solution for this problem and also I want to study this equation in a very general way, applicable to some other equations !

Comment: Well you sort of *need* to invoke the form of $f$ here I think. Unfortunately, there is not really one nice technique which works for PDEs in general.

Comment: Non-negative solutions of the heat equation are unique, see for example John's book.

Comment: I saw in John's book that it was true when $d=1$, but I read nothing about the case $d>1$. Is that still true ?